# SO users weekly reputation reports accumulative rep gained for two weeks instead of one week

Tags: bug, reputation, users-page

---

**Edit/Update 2**: *On Sunday (19th July 2020 @ UTC 00:00) the weekly reputation counter has reset to zero. This is now resolved and is functioning as per expected system behaviour.*

---

**Edit/Update**: *On Friday (17th July 2020), some counter seems to have reset. The weekly reputation is now correctly reporting the rep gained for a single week duration. At present, it shows the correct rep count for the period starting: Sunday 12th July 2020 to present date (Saturday 18th July 2020).*

---

On Stack Overflow, a user's weekly reputation currently reports the accumulative reputation gained for a two week period instead of one week.

#### Steps to reproduce the issue/bug:

1. Visit https://stackoverflow.com/users
2. Enter a user name, e.g. `RobC`
3. Ensure the `Reputation` and `week` options are chosen.

---

[image: Screenshot showing results for searching for RobC]

---

#### Expected result:

The username `RobC` *(indicated in box 4 above)* to report a reputation gain of `30` for this week.

#### Actual result:

The username `RobC` *(indicated in box 4 above)* currently reports a reputation gain of `117` for this week.

---

#### Additional information:

If you visit the *[Reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611459/robc?tab=reputation)* section for user `RobC` - *also shown in the screenshot below*.

You can see that:

1. The reputation gained by `RobC` this week is `30`.
2. The reputation gained by `RobC` last week was `87`.
3. The total reputation gained by `RobC` this week and last week is `117`.

[image]

Comment: Can reproduce on SO but not here and a few other sites I checked.

Comment: I just had a look at the profile of ChrisF on SO, for that account the week reputation is the reputation gained in the last 8 days. Jul 5 - now.

Comment: @Luuklag - yes you're correct, "8 days" is actualy more accurate. In my OP I was rounding to weeks - Today you could change the words _"two week(s)"_ in my OP with _8 days_. It's the same thing - essentially some counter is not getting reset somewhere.

Comment: It probably has to do with some rounding. 7 -> 8, because of timezones involved etc.

Comment: @Luuklag - In which case that's a change from what normal. For the last x years when I log into SO on a Monday morning, lets say 9:00 [GMT](https://greenwichmeantime.com/) the counter has already been reset. It states [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83014/week-reputation-and-date-time-representation-standards/83016#83016): _"stackexchange.com leagues use the same reset-on-sunday week"_ and _"We stick with a consistent UTC 00:00 reset every day for many things"_

Comment: Isn't this due to having different definitions for what is a week?